# Question about simplex method mentioned in A. Schrijver's book

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

I am reading section 1 of chapter 11 of A. Schrijver's book Theory of Linear and Integer Programming. He frist introduces how to find an optimal solution of LP problem $$\max\{cx|Ax\le b\}$$ if you know a vertex $x_0$ of the polyhedron $P=\{x|Ax\le b\}$.

Then he discusses the general case if no initial vertex is know. Consider the LP problem $$\max\{cx|x\ge 0,Ax\le b\}$$ He says "we can write $Ax\le b$ as $A_1x\le b_1,A_2x\ge b_2$ with $b_1\ge 0$ and $b_2>0$. Consider $$\max\{\mathbf{1}(A_2x-\tilde{x})|x,\tilde{x}\ge 0; A_1x\le b_1,A_2x-\tilde{x}\le b_2\}$$

If the maximum value of the new LP is less than $\textbf{1}b_2$, then the original LP is infeasible."
 I am confused about what is $A_1,b_1$ and $A_2,b_2.$ How can we write $A_2\ge b_2$ but the original one is $Ax\le b$? And why $\mathbf{1}b_2$ counts in the discussion?

Answer (score 0):

We can split $Ax\le b$ into $A_1 x \le b_1, b_1\ge 0$ and $A_2 x \le b_2, b_2 < 0$. The last expression is identical to $-A_2 x \ge b_2, b_2>0$. Renaming $A_2$ we can write this as $A_2 x \ge b_2, b_2>0$